# Retrieving HTML time input type with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Using HTML input type in format `HH:MM:SS` (with step = "1"), when we do get value we get `HH:MM` when SS = "00".

*Example:*

When you retrieve `23:00:00` in JS you will get `23:00` only while it should be `23:00:00`.

Please see the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/t29cqL82/2/

Comment: Is your question how to retrieve the value as `23:00:00` rather than `23:00`?  What code are you using to grab/display the value? What does your HTML `<input>` element look like? Is this part of a form?

Comment: Yes , you can see the fiddle , if you enter 23:00:00 and press the button. JS shows 23:00 only

Comment: What browser are you using? It shows up correctly as `23:00:00` in IE 11.

Comment: The issue is with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is editing the value.

```
var time = "";
var timeArray= time.split(":");

if (timeArray[2] == "00" || !timeArray[2]){
   time = timeArray[0]+":"+timeArray[1] + ":00"
}
```

Comment: If `time` only consists of two sections (`HH:MM`) this answer won't add seconds onto the end.

Answer (score 0):

In IE11, the time parses correctly and the alert box shows `23:00:00`. However, since not everyone is lucky enough to have such a robust and state-of-the-art browser, here are a couple of solutions you could implement:

### Parse as a string

Instead of grabbing the time as a value, grab it as a string. You can do this by changing your `time` declaration statement to:

```
var time = "" + document.getElementById("myTime").value;
```

### Add the seconds

You can tack the `:00` onto the end of your `time` variable with an `if` statement and a couple of lines of code:

```
if (time.split(":").length < 3) {
  time = time + ":00";
}
```

Note that with this method, if the user inputs `23:00` it be converted to `23:00:00`.